# how to sharpen/soften an image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I am in MATLAB R2012a and am trying to soften images. Now I am trying to sharpen and soften images that I converted into matrices of doubles. I know there are functions to do just this but I have to do it manually, using math and such. So please tell me how does one sharpen or soften an image?

Comment: This site provides some filter matrices for sharpening: http://www.foundalis.com/res/imgproc.htm It isn't enough to answer your question but should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

TO sharp the image you can use
B = imsharpen(A) returns an enhanced version of the grayscale or truecolor (RGB) input image A, where the image features, such as edges

To blur or soften the image you can use.

h = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma) returns a rotationally symmetric Gaussian lowpass filter of size hsize with standard deviation sigma (positive). hsize can be a vector specifying the number of rows and columns in h, or it can be a scalar, in which case h is a square matrix. The default value for hsize is [3 3]; the default value for sigma is 0.5.

Comment: You can go behind the function to find the source code for the functions

Comment: MATLAB2012a doesn't have imsharpen()

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to use the functions, I guess this is what you need for your homework. To obtain a sharpen image you can subtract the blur image from the original image and to obtain a blur image from your original one, you need to apply mean filter.